# Live video feed from camera to tkinter window with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am currently trying to get live webcam feed to a box in my gui. The box i am trying to get it in is the one labeled "Video Feed". cap = cv2.videoCapture(0) is my video input. I don't know how to go about implementing the live video into tkinter and opencv. I added both files needed to run this program, ui2.py and settings.py below.

ui2.py:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as tk
import cv2

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Traffic Camera")
root.geometry("+0+0")
root.iconbitmap('car_icon.ico')

width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
root.configure(bg='#FFFFFF')
root.pack()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


def main():
    global state, user_email, user_speed, user_location, rec, line1, line2, settings_button, help_button

    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    if state == "settings":
        email_save.destroy()
        speed_save.destroy()
        location_save.destroy()
        back_button.destroy()
    elif state == "help":
        back_button.destroy()
    state = "main"

    time = str(datetime.time(datetime.now()).hour) + ":" + str(datetime.time(datetime.now()).minute)
    mics_info = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFFFFF', text=user_location + " / " + str(date.today()) + " / " + time, font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width/4, height/8, anchor='sw', window=mics_info)

    rec = root.create_rectangle(width/4, height/8, width/4*3, height/8*6)
    line1 = root.create_line(width/4, height/8, width/4*3, height/8*6)
    line2 = root.create_line(width/4*3, height/8, width/4, height/8*6)
    video_feed = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFFFFF', text="Video Feed", font='bold')
    root.create_window(width/2, height/16*7, anchor='center', window=video_feed)

    speed_limit = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFFFFF', text="Speed Limit: " + str(user_speed) + " mph", font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width/4, height/8*6+1, anchor='nw', window=speed_limit)

    email = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFFFFF', text="Email: " + user_email, font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width/4*3, height/8*6+1, anchor='ne', window=email)
    settings_button = tk.Button(text='Settings', width=10, font=('', 12), command=settings)
    root.create_window(width/2-20, height/8*7, anchor='e', window=settings_button)

    help_button = tk.Button(text='Help', width=10, font=('', 12), command=help)
    root.create_window(width/2+20, height/8*7, anchor='w', window=help_button)


def settings():
    global state, user_email, user_speed, user_location, email_field, speed_field, location_field, \
        email_save, speed_save, location_save, back_button

    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    root.delete(rec)
    root.delete(line1)
    root.delete(line2)
    settings_button.destroy()
    help_button.destroy()
    state = "settings"

    settings_title = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFFFFF', text="Settings", font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width/2, height/20, anchor='center', window=settings_title)

    email_label = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFFFFF', text="Email", font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width/2-100, height/20*3, anchor='e', window=email_label)
    email_field = tk.Entry(root, width=30, bd=3)
    root.create_window(width/2, height/20*3, anchor='center', window=email_field)

    email_save = tk.Button(text='Save', width=10, font=('', 12), command=save_email)
    root.create_window(width/5*3, height/20*3, anchor='w', window=email_save)

    speed_label = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFFFFF', text="Speed Limit", font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width/2-100, height/20*4.5, anchor='e', window=speed_label)
    speed_field = tk.Entry(root, width=30, bd=3)
    root.create_window(width/2, height/20*4.5, anchor='center', window=speed_field)

    speed_save = tk.Button(text='Save', width=10, font=('', 12), command=save_speed)
    root.create_window(width/5*3, height/20*4.5, anchor='w', window=speed_save)

    location_label = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFFFFF', text="Location", font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width/2-100, height/20*6, anchor='e', window=location_label)
    location_field = tk.Entry(root, width=30, bd=3)
    root.create_window(width/2, height/20*6, anchor='center', window=location_field)

    location_save = tk.Button(text='Save', width=10, font=('', 12), command=save_location)
    root.create_window(width/5*3, height/20*6, anchor='w', window=location_save)

    back_button = tk.Button(text='Back', width=10, font=('', 12), command=main)
    root.create_window(width/2, height/20*8, anchor='center', window=back_button)


def help():
    global state, back_button

    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    root.delete(rec)
    root.delete(line1)
    root.delete(line2)
    settings_button.destroy()
    help_button.destroy()
    state = "help"

    help_title = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFFFFF', text="Help", font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width/2, height/20, anchor='center', window=help_title)

    getting_started = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFFFFF', text="Getting Started", font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width/2, height/20*3, anchor='center', window=getting_started)

    s_text = """Upon starting the program, you will be greeted by the home
        page of the Traffic Camera software. Here, you can view the live feed 
        of the traffic camera, its location, its speed threshold, the email, 
        as well as the time and date. At the bottom of the 
        screen are two buttons which allow access to the settings page and the 
        help page."""
    start_text = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFFFFF', text=s_text, font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width/2, height/20*4, anchor='n', window=start_text)

    settings = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFFFFF', text="Settings", font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width/2, height/20*9, anchor='center', window=settings)

    settings_text = """Upon clicking the 'Settings' button on the home page, 
        a window will be presented giving you a couple options that allow
        modification. The first text box allows you to manipulate the current
        email that will be notified. The second text box allows you to 
        manipulate the speed threshold of the traffic camera. The third text box 
        allows you to manipulate the current location of the traffic camera. 
        Clicking on the 'Save' button next to these text boxes modifies the value
        of the respective text box. Once your changes are complete, 
        clicking on the 'Back' button will bring you back to the home page, where 
        the updated information will be displayed."""
    settings_label = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFFFFF', text=settings_text, font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width/2, height/20*10, anchor='n', window=settings_label)

    back_button = tk.Button(text='Back', width=10, font=('', 12), command=main)
    root.create_window(width/2, height/20*16, anchor='center', window=back_button)


def save_email():
    global user_email, email_field
    user_email = email_field.get()


def save_speed():
    global user_speed, speed_field
    user_speed = speed_field.get()


def save_location():
    global user_location, location_field
    user_location = location_field.get()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global state, user_email, user_speed, user_location
    user_email = "example@web.com"
    user_speed = 25
    user_location = "Location"
    state = "main"
    main()
    root.mainloop()
```

settings.py:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Settings")
root.iconbitmap('car_icon.ico')

width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth() / 3, root.winfo_screenheight() / 2
root = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
root.configure(bg='#235937')
root.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    settings_title = tk.Label(root,bg='#235937', text="Settings", font=('', 20, 'bold'), fg='#FFFFFF')
    root.create_window(width / 2, height / 12, anchor='center', window=settings_title)

    email_field = tk.Entry(root, width=30, bd=3)
    root.create_window(width / 2, height / 4, anchor='e', window=email_field)

    email_save = tk.Button(text='SAVE', width=10, height=1, font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width / 2 + 75, height / 4, anchor='w', window=email_save)

    speed_field = tk.Entry(root, width=30, bd=3)
    root.create_window(width / 2, height / 4 + 50, anchor='e', window=speed_field)

    speed_save = tk.Button(text='SAVE', width=10, height=1, font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width / 2 + 75, height / 4 + 50, anchor='w', window=speed_save)

    local_field = tk.Entry(root, width=30, bd=3)
    root.create_window(width / 2, height / 4 + 100, anchor='e', window=local_field)

    local_save = tk.Button(text='SAVE', width=10, height=1, font=('', 12))
    root.create_window(width / 2 + 75, height / 4 + 100, anchor='w', window=local_save)

    back_button = tk.Button(text='BACK', width=10, height=1, font=('',12))
    root.create_window(width / 2, height / 2 + 150, anchor='center', window=back_button)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So you want to show the live capture on a label?

Comment: I want to  have the live video feed where the label is

Comment: This is very easy please find examples on google

Comment: @Jonamite There are quite many things you are doing wrong. Sorry,  I might not be able to help. Btw did you have a look at these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922175/to-show-video-streaming-inside-frame-in-tkinter) [link2](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/05/30/displaying-a-video-feed-with-opencv-and-tkinter/)?

Answer (score 2):

This example would solve your problem; it shows the essentials how to integrate tkinter and CV2 to "discuss between" fluently. Follow the principle, and add your code "on top" of this example, and that's it!

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

ikkuna=tkinter.Tk()
ikkuna.title("Example about handy CV2 and tkinter combination...")

frame=np.random.randint(0,255,[100,100,3],dtype='uint8')
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(frame))

paneeli_image=tkinter.Label(ikkuna) #,image=img)
paneeli_image.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,pady=1,padx=10)

message="You can see some \nclassification results \nhere after you add some intelligent  \nadditional code to your combined and handy \n tkinter & CV2 solution!"
paneeli_text=tkinter.Label(ikkuna,text=message)
paneeli_text.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=1,padx=10)

global cam

def otakuva():
    global frame
    global cam
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    #cv2.namedWindow("Experience_in_AI camera")
    while True:
        ret, frame = cam.read()

        #Update the image to tkinter...
        frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img_update = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(frame))
        paneeli_image.configure(image=img_update)
        paneeli_image.image=img_update
        paneeli_image.update()

        if not ret:
            print("failed to grab frame")
            break

        k = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if k%256 == 27:
            # ESC pressed
            print("Escape hit, closing...")

            cam.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

def lopeta():
    global cam
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("Stopped!")

painike_korkeus=10
painike_1=tkinter.Button(ikkuna,text="Start",command=otakuva,height=5,width=20)
painike_1.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=10,padx=10)
painike_1.config(height=1*painike_korkeus,width=20)

painike_korkeus=10
painike_1=tkinter.Button(ikkuna,text="Stop",command=lopeta,height=5,width=20)
painike_1.grid(row=1,column=2,pady=10,padx=10)
painike_1.config(height=1*painike_korkeus,width=20)

ikkuna.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on @[Experience-In-Ai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15519629/experience-in-ai)'s answer **:**

you can use this code, not to get errors while pressing the stop button:

```
while (cam.isOpened()):
   ...
```

and not to get errors while pressing the close button:

```
def on_closing():
    global cam
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    ikkuna.destroy()

ikkuna.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

ikkuna.mainloop()
```